# ingress-nginx not listening on Port 80

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kind, ingress-nginx

I have a KinD cluster on my laptop where I am attempting to use `ingress-nginx` to provide a way to access UIs for services running in the cluster, at this stage just prometheus and argocd.

I'm having an infuriating issue when installing with helm, it just won't listen on port 80 and I have to use a port-forward for the service to be able to access it, i.e `prometheus.example.com:54644`, rather than just being able to hit `prometheus.example.com`.

When I install ingress-nginx via this command everything works exactly as I expect:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/main/deploy/static/provider/kind/deploy.yaml
```

A nodepool service is created and navigating to prometheus.example.com gives me the expected UI.

However, when installing via Helm so I can enable the ingress-nginx prometheus metrics with the following command I have to use the aforementioned port forwarding to access the UI.

```
helm upgrade -i ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx -n ingress-nginx  --create-namespace --set controller.metrics.enabled=true --set-string controller.podAnnotations."prometheus\.io/scrape"="true" --set-string controller.podAnnotations."prometheus\.io/port"="10254"
```

Kind’s documentation does state that the manifest I first listed includes patches to forward the hostports, I just can't see what they are from reviewing the yaml.  Can anyone summarise it for me so I can patch my helm deployment appropriately?

Comment: Try check out again the content from `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/main/deploy/static/provider/kind/deploy.yaml`. It do a lot more than just port forwarding, it create some resources and set a few configurations for the nginx ingress-controller pod. I bet the safest path to learn what you need to is to save a local copy of the raw manifest (from the first cmd), add the desired annotations on it and then apply your updated version of the raw manifest instead of use helm

Comment: You can use `--set-string` to change the service type to nodeport.